# How to add only one click event on a label?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

Hello i'm trying to add an event of click on a button when the user click a label, 
its working fine but the user have to click on the label twice i need to make it work from the first click
this is my function :

```
(function($){



$('.next-on-click .forminator-checkbox-label').on('click', function() {
    $('button.forminator-button.forminator-button-next').trigger('click');
});




})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Can you please add html code in question as well and you want to add click event on label then what should be the next response on it ? Can you please provide more information on it.

Comment: if the user click on the label -> automatically i should have a click on the next button ( its a multi step form )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<lable class="next"> Next </lable>
<button class="check">Check</button>

<script>
$('.next').click(function() {
alert("Hi");
    $('button.check').trigger('click');
});
</script>
```

Comment: also i have to click twice

Comment: @Maryam Can you please add your code with html and scripts in question, it would be easy to understand or add fiddler ?

Comment: the html is so huge this is why t did not put it here but i can provide the link to the page i need help with , its https://isowatt.fr/test/

Comment: @Maryam - I did test and it seems working fine for me. I  submitted one complete form process and on just one click on label it triggered the button click event.

Comment: could you please show the code that you use because for now i have to do double click as you can see if you try now

Comment: @Maryam -Just wanted to understand - when I click on any label under "Type de demande *" it should redirect me to next form ? Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: yes exactely that what should happen but in my case i have to double click the lable

Comment: I tried this `$('.forminator-checkbox-label').click(function() {
    $('.forminator-button-next').trigger('click');
});
`

but it is working partially and it seems like there is another event which is working on add font color to the label. Try remove that event and add only click event on lable.

Answer (score 0):

example:

```
$('.next-on-click .forminator-checkbox-label').on('dblclick', function() {
    $('button.forminator-button.forminator-button-next').trigger('click');
})
```

Comment: thank you but it still not working

Answer (score 0):

So why would you need JavaScript to handle the click? Adding an for attribute on a label will click the button.

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function () {
  console.log("clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="btn">Label</label>
<button id="btn">Button</button>
```